# RestKit value transformer validation block not called

Tags: ios, restkit

I'm using RestKit (the latest version 0.23.1), and I have defined a custom transformer between a string value to a number field as follows:

```
mapping.valueTransformer = [RKBlockValueTransformer valueTransformerWithValidationBlock:^BOOL(__unsafe_unretained Class inputValueClass, __unsafe_unretained Class outputValueClass) {
    return [inputValueClass isSubclassOfClass:[NSString class]];
} transformationBlock:^BOOL(id inputValue, __autoreleasing id *outputValue, __unsafe_unretained Class outputClass, NSError *__autoreleasing *error) {
    if (![inputValue isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
        return NO;
    }

    // conversion logic follows...
    return YES;
}];
```

The transformer works properly, however the validation block is not being called (I've set a breakpoint to verify that), which forces me to check in the transformationBlock that the inputValue is indeed an instance of NSString.

Why is the validation block not being invoked, what am I doing wrong?
I couldn't find any issue on this in RestKit GitHub page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the transformer directly onto the mapping and as the only transformer so it is assumed that it always applies.

You want to set the transformer to a `RKCompoundValueTransformer` (Using `defaultValueTransformer` And your custom transformer) as it does perform validation before applying transformations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)
I'm guessing though if that's the case then it is simply better to perform the validation in the transformation block instead of using RKCompoundValueTransformer. I mean, what will I gain here by using the defaultValueTransformer?

Comment: Also, if I do `[RKValueTransformer defaultValueTransformer] addValueTransformer:...]` this will cause my transformer to be invoked every time an NSString is converted into NSNumber which is not what I want.

Comment: You apply the new compound to your mapping in the same way. Your transformer needs to be first. The compound just does the validation and handles any other required transformation for that mapping.